# fast-report close designer without save dialog

Tags: c#, fastreport

I'm working on an application that uses fast-report.
If I modified the report and close the designer window I get asked if I want to save "Untitled.frx". How can I prevent this dialog from appearing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `AskSave` property:

```
        var report = new Report();
        Config.DesignerSettings.DesignerLoaded += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            report.Designer.AskSave = false;
        };
        report.Design();
```

Comment: i've added an more detailed expample. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem. The DesignerSettings_DesignerClosed method is to prevent problems if i reopen the Designer later.
Thanks [@Grzegorz Brzęczyszczykiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4667434/grzegorz-brz%C4%99czyszczykiewicz) for the tip with AskSave().

```
    ...
    {
        Config.DesignerSettings.DesignerLoaded += DesignerSettings_DesignerLoaded;
        Config.DesignerSettings.DesignerClosed += DesignerSettings_DesignerClosed;
        Report.ReportData.Design(false);
    }


    private void DesignerSettings_DesignerClosed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Config.DesignerSettings.DesignerLoaded -= DesignerSettings_DesignerLoaded;
        Config.DesignerSettings.DesignerClosed -= DesignerSettings_DesignerClosed;
    }


    private void DesignerSettings_DesignerLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Report.ReportData.Designer.AskSave = false;
    }
```